# Is there anyway to test memory leak with iPodMusicPlayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, instruments

I am trying to test memory leak for my app that used of `MPMusicPlayerController's` `iPodMusicPlayer`.

As a music Player that must use iPod Library and can play songs on physical devices , can't in iOS `Simulator`.

Now i want to test memory leak of my app with `Instrument`.

Is there anyway to test it with `Instrument`?

Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode have some tools for test memory leaks. run -> Start with Performance Tool -> Leaks. 
You can learn how to use it from [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHWGUwYMGBw) video.